# How to disable multi selection in a wxGrid?

Tags: wxwidgets

I want to select only one row in wxGrid.
Is is possible to disable multiselection in a wxGrid?
I tried `SetSelectionMode`, it helps me to select only rows. But I cannot use it for single row selection.

Answer (score 1):

Capture the wxEVT_GRID_SELECT_CELL event.

Use GetSelectedRows() to obtain an array of selected rows.

If there are more than one row selected -

- Use SelectRow() to deselect everything except, say, the first row in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    wx.EVT_MOTION(self.grid.GetGridWindow(), self.OnMouseMotion)
    wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN(self.grid.GetGridWindow(), self.OnMouseLeftDown)
    wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN(self.grid.GetGridWindow(), self.OnKeyPress)

def OnMouseMotion(self,event):
    if event.Dragging():
        return
    else: 
        event.Skip()

def OnMouseLeftDown(self,event):
    if event.AltDown() or event.ShiftDown() or event.ControlDown():
        return
    else:
        event.Skip()

def OnKeyPress(self,event):
    if event.GetKeyCode() in [wx.WXK_SHIFT,wx.WXK_ALT,wx.WXK_CONTROL,wx.WXK_UP,wx.WXK_DOWN,]:
        return
    else:
        event.Skip()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that this question is quite old but there not so much on this argument in internet.

Many of the solution posted on internet are not completed or with some quirks.
Here's my solution. I've a class that inherit wxGrid, with the following methods

```
void ReportGrid::DisableRangeHandler (wxGridRangeSelectEvent &ev)
{
    if( ev.Selecting() && (ev.GetTopRow() != ev.GetBottomRow()) ) {
        ev.StopPropagation();
        ev.Veto();
    }
}

void ReportGrid::DisableRangeSelectCellHandler (wxGridEvent &ev)
{
    SelectRow(ev.GetRow());
}

void ReportGrid::DisableCtrlMaiusHandler (wxGridEvent &ev)
{
    if (ev.ControlDown() || ev.ShiftDown()){
        ev.Veto();
    } else {
        ev.Skip();
    }
}

void ReportGrid::DisableDraggingHandler (wxMouseEvent &ev)
{
    if (ev.Dragging()){
        ev.Skip(false);
    }
}

void ReportGrid::SingleSelectionMode(bool enabled)
{
    if (_singleSelection == enabled){
        return;
    }
    if (enabled){
        Bind(wxEVT_GRID_RANGE_SELECT, &ReportGrid::DisableRangeHandler, this);
        Bind(wxEVT_GRID_SELECT_CELL, &ReportGrid::DisableRangeSelectCellHandler, this);
        Bind(wxEVT_GRID_CELL_LEFT_CLICK, &ReportGrid::DisableCtrlMaiusHandler, this);
        GetGridWindow()->Bind(wxEVT_MOTION, &ReportGrid::DisableDraggingHandler, this);
        _singleSelection = true;
    } else {
        Unbind(wxEVT_GRID_RANGE_SELECT, &ReportGrid::DisableRangeHandler, this);
        Unbind(wxEVT_GRID_SELECT_CELL, &ReportGrid::DisableRangeSelectCellHandler, this);
        Unbind(wxEVT_GRID_CELL_LEFT_CLICK, &ReportGrid::DisableCtrlMaiusHandler, this);
        GetGridWindow()->Unbind(wxEVT_MOTION, &ReportGrid::DisableDraggingHandler, this);
        _singleSelection = false;
    }
}
```

This is the closest i've been to have a single row selection on wxWidgets.